# LinQ: ?: Operator in select query

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a query like below. anyone have idea why the **?:** parts are always return false values although there is item contains in LIST.  Or anyone have better idea to write this query, feel free to reply here. thanks.

```
List EList = new List();
EList.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, "a1", "b1"));
EList.Add(new EmployeeInfo(2, "a2", "b2"));
List OList = new List();
OList.Add(new EmployeeInfo(1, "a1", "b1"));
OList.Add(new EmployeeInfo(2, "a2", "b2"));
OList.Add(new EmployeeInfo(3, "aa2", "bb2"));

var results = (
    from e in b
    select new
    {
        Id = e.ID,
        Name = e.Name,
        Email = e.Email,
        IS_Elist = (EList.Contains(e))?true:false,
        IS_Olist = (OList.Contains(e)) ? true : false,
    }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Wait, what? `?true:false` is totally redundant.  Just say `IS_Elist = Elist.Contains(e), IS_Olist = Olist.Contains(e)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can simplify your query - `expression ? : true : false` is equivalent to just `expression` and we get the following.

```
var results = b.Select(e => new
                            {
                                Id = e.ID,
                                Name = e.Name,
                                Email = e.Email,
                                IS_Elist = EList.Contains(e),
                                IS_Olist = OList.Contains(e)
                             })
               .ToList();
```

This should and will definitely yield `true` if an item from `b` is contained in `EList` or `OList`. If you always get `false` this means that `EList` and `OList` do not contain any items from `b`. Remember that you are probably doing a comparison of references and therefore

```
new EmployeeInfo(1, "a", "b") == new EmployeeInfo(1, "a", "b")
```

will usually yield `false`.

I guess you actually intended a comparison by `ID`.

```
var results = b.Select(e => new
                            {
                                Id = e.ID,
                                Name = e.Name,
                                Email = e.Email,
                                IS_Elist = EList.Any(x => x.ID == e.ID),
                                IS_Olist = OList.Any(x => x.ID == e.ID)
                             })
               .ToList();
```

The alternative solution is to implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) on `EmployeeInfo` or overriding [`Equals()`, `GetHashCode()` and the equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx.aspx). You should take care that all your implementations yield consistent results or you will end with a lot of confusion why for example `Object.Equals()` and the equality operator yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

Your equality check may not be behaving as you expect for EmployeeInfo. To confirm, at the bottom of the snippet you posted above, try this and see if it returns true.

```
var is_olist = OList.Contains(new EmployeeInfo(1, "a1", "b1"));
```

If this returns false, you need to consider using something simpler but still unique to compare instances (such as the ID member), or else implement equals yourself in EmployeeInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Equals and the Equality == operator in your EmployeeInfo class.

[Implementing the Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h9bszxx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Guidelines for Implementing Equals and the Equality Operator (==)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)